# configure docker network bridge IP for multiple IP alias

Tags: networking, docker

I got a Ubuntu host with **multiple IP address aliases** and I want to expose the ports from docker containers connected to one docker **network bridge** to a **specific IP address of the host** and the ports from the other containers to the other IP address of the host.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do this:

```
docker network create -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="114.176.98.13" network1
```

this way exported ports are available at this IP but not on other IP addresses of the host.

Comment: It should be noted that this creates a bridge interface, and that you cannot create multiple host interfaces which are limited to just one of the IPs on the host, Which is discussed as an open issue here: https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/976